# Trouble with MySQL: CONCAT_WS(' ', name_first, name_middle, name_last) like '%keyword%'

Tags: php, mysql

hey folks, I'm setting up a keyword search across multiple fields: name_first, name_middle, name_last but I'm not getting the results I'd like. Here's the query:

```
    "SELECT accounts_users.user_ID, users.name_first, users.name_middle, users.name_last, users.company
   FROM accounts_users, users
   WHERE accounts_users.account_ID = '$account_ID' AND accounts_users.user_ID = users.id AND CONCAT_WS(' ', users.name_first, users.name_middle, users.name_last) LIKE '$user_keyword%'
   ORDER BY users.name_first ASC"
```

So, if I've got three names in the DB:

Aaron J Ban
Aaron J Can
Bob L Lawblaw

And if the user_keyword == "bob lawblaw" I get no result. If user_keyword == "bob L" then it returns Bob L Lawblaw. Obviously I can't force people to include the persons middle name in their keyword search but I'm stuck for the proper way to do this.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially look into creating a full text index on those 3 columns and then doing a full text search on that.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

**##UPDATE##**

if using INNODB, then maybe use php's `split` function on the string;

```
$myVars = split(" ",$user_keyword);
```

then add a select statement for each word (I would also use the concat in the select statment so youu dont have to reapeat it for each where statement)

```
$extraSQL = '';
foreach($myVars as $search) {
    $extraSQL .= " AND `my_concat` LIKE '%".$search."%'";
}

SELECT 
    `your_fields`, 
    CONCAT_WS(' ', users.name_first, users.name_middle, users.name_last) as `my_concat` 
FROM `your_tables`
WHERE `accounts_users`.account_ID = '$account_ID' . $extraSQL;
```

Comment: hey Lizard,

Thanks for the idea but I'm using INNODB tables so my understanding is that I don't have that option as it's only available for MyISAM tables.

Comment: hey Lizard, looks like it just might. I haven't had a chance to give it a shot yet but will tomorrow and post back. Thanks again for the help.